# looking to host .mp3 or wav files online to use with react-sound. accessible through url.

Tags: reactjs, audio, redux, web-hosting, audio-streaming

So i'm building a react page where you can select between a few different music choices to run in the background.  I've got npm's react-sound running.  It works great I found an example online and i used this guys link to an audio track online to test it all out.  So easy! Took 10 minutes to set it up exactly the way i wanted it to in my app.  Now, i cannot figure out how to host a track somewhere on the web where i can simple visit it's url so react-sound can play the audio.  Any suggestions? For free? This site will have very few visits.  Just a personal project. React-sound takes a url with a .mp3 or .wav. Example: "http://www.nihilus.net/soundtracks/Static%20Memories.mp3". Which works!

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Sound from 'react-sound';
import { Audio } from 'redux-audio';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import muiThemeable from 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import OptionsForm from './options/OptionsForm';
import Login from './Login';
import Profile from './Profile';

class Landing extends Component {
    onChangeForm({ theme, genre }) {
        this.props.setTheme({ theme });
        if (genre === 'silence') {
            this.props.setAudio({ genre, status: 'STOPPED' });
        } else if (genre) {
            this.props.setAudio({ genre, status: 'PLAYING' });
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.props.fetchUser();
        if (this.props.auth && this.props.auth.options.length > 0) {
            const { theme, genre } = this.props.auth.options[0];
            this.props.setTheme({ theme });
            if (genre === 'silence') {
                this.props.setAudio({ genre, status: 'STOPPED' });
            } else if (genre) {
                this.props.setAudio({ genre, status: 'PLAYING' });
            }
        }
    }

    renderOptions() {
        if (this.props.auth) {
            const {
                options,
                linkedinDisplayName,
                googleDisplayName,
                facebookDisplayName
            } = this.props.auth;
            switch (options.length > 0) {
                case true:
                    return (
                        <Profile
                            name={
                                linkedinDisplayName || googleDisplayName || facebookDisplayName
                            }
                        />
                    );
                default:
                    return <OptionsForm onChange={this.onChangeForm.bind(this)} />;
            }
        }

        return <Login />;
    }

    // you are here
    // can you access mp3s from dropbox?
    renderAudio() {
        let audioURL = '';
        let playStatus = '';
        switch (this.props.audioOptions.genre) {
            case 'dance':
                audioURL = 'https://clyp.it/0r0v0cdm';
                break;
            case 'rock':
                audioURL = 'http://www.nihilus.net/soundtracks/Static%20Memories.mp3';
                break;
            case 'folk':
                audioURL = 'http://hosting.tropo.com/5071426/www/audio/classical.mp3';
                break;
            case 'classical':
                audioURL =
                    'http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/mozart-horn-concerto4-3-rondo.mp3';
                break;
            default:
                audioURL = '';
                break;
        }

        if (this.props.audioOptions.status === 'PLAYING') {
            playStatus = Sound.status.PLAYING;

            return (
                <Sound
                    url={audioURL}
                    playStatus={playStatus}
                    // playFromPosition={300 /* in milliseconds */}
                    // onLoading={this.handleSongLoading}
                    // onPlaying={this.handleSongPlaying}
                    // onFinishedPlaying={this.handleSongFinishedPlaying}
                />
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderAudio()}
                {this.renderOptions()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ auth, audioOptions }) {
    return { auth, audioOptions };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(muiThemeable()(Landing));
```

Comment: I'm confused... what exactly are you trying to do?  From the question it sounds like you're just looking for static web hosting?

Comment: Yes, that was all i was looking for.  Just wanted somewhere to host audio that could be accessed by react-sound via url and wasn't too sure what was required to make it work.  Had issues with the first couple services i tried (dropbox and tropo) but ended up hosting some audio on an amazon s3 free tier account.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special is required.  Any static HTTP/HTTPS hosting will do.

As you have found, a common way to do this is S3.  If you have high traffic, use a CDN like CloudFront, which can be configured in front of your S3 bucket.